# {size} is displayed unformatted?

Tags: assets

I have the following code:

```
    {cf_concerts_media_assets var_prefix="asset"}
        <li><a class="download_icon" href="{asset:url}">{if asset:title}{asset:title}{if:else}{asset:filename}{/if} ({asset:size})</a></li>
    {/cf_concerts_media_assets}
```

with or without the prefix it is rendering the size in bytes instead of the formatted version?
I am on EE 2.5.5 and assets 2.0.3

cheers
stefan

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug - it will be fixed in the next release - I'll send you a hotfix shortly so you don't have to suffer for our silly mistakes, provided your email is still the same :)

Comment: thanks for the file, I got it, but that didn't help at all... the size is still in bytes... it's not that bad, I can wait for the update. but if you want me to try again, I'm happy to test. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there was another bug which prevented this from working with var_prefix. Will be fixed in the next release, but you can just replace line 553 in helper.php with

```
if (empty($file_vars[$var_prefix.$key]))
```

and that should hot-fix your issue while we get the next release out the door.

Cheers,
Andris

Answer (score 2):

This should have been fixed in Assets 2.0.4, which we released today.

Comment: hi brandon, sorry, but the update didn't fix the issue. I've run module updates, I've cleared caches, I've tried with a custom title... but nothing made it work...